# The length of radio button value is more than expected

Tags: sql, radio-button

I use the following query to update a row. I used `response.write` to check the query after receiving the form from HTML page and I have to say that the value of `status` field is being read from a radio button:

html radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="active">
```

check line at collector page:

```
update products set title=N'some titile',price='50000',refer='4',
status=N'active',ispublic=N'yes',isproduct=N'yes' where id=12
```

after that when I select the the data in an asp page and I check the length of `status` field which holds the word **active**, it shows **10** instead of **6**

```
sql="select * from products where id=12"
rs.open sql,objcon
response.write len(rs("status"))
rs.close
```

Are there any hidden character after the word **active** or there is a common mistake elsewhere?

Comment: which db you are really using and which datatype is the column value?

Comment: SQL server 2016 and the field is `nvarchar50` @scaisEdge

Comment: Sorry. I have checked again and the type of field was set to `nchar`. I think this was the exact case. Thank you @scaisEdge